# error while installing ubuntu 14.10

Tags: 12.04

i finished downloading the iso file to usb and im trying to install through usb but unable to do so  the error is as follows:
Asking for cache data failed unable to find a medium containing a live file system can you please guide as to what needs to be done here  i tried reading and executing all your answers but was unable to do so. kindly let me know in detail(step by step) procedure as to how to go about it.
thanks :-)
AJ

Comment: You can wait 3 more days for Ubuntu 15.04 to arrive. Note that 14.10. will be supported just for another 3 months. So, what OS do you use(I assume Ubuntu 12.04 since you tag it)?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you are in windows trying to make a bootable usb stick of Ubuntu.

Download [this](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/universal-usb-installer-easy-as-1-2-3/#button) tool, which will help you make your usb stick a bootable one by extracting the files on the iso to the usb memory stick.

After extracting, boot up with the usb. Prior to installation, if you haven't installed Linux OS's before, please read on that.

(How to use this software are given in simple, in the above website itself).